# AppFuse Save two new entities at once

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, appfuse

I'm trying to save 2 entities in AppFuse (Struts2, Hibernate and Spring) at once, 
Here is an example (Address and person are new objects):

```
person.setAddress(address);
personManager.save(person);
```

But this doesn't work, i get this exception:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
instance before merge
```

I have to do:

```
addressManager.save(address);
person.setAddress(address);
personManager.save(person);
```

In person model i have declared Address like that:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address
}
```

Are there any way to save this new entities at once?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below may helpful for you

Have you fallowed as given in [docs_oracle_javax_persistence_OneToMany.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)
**Example 1:** One-to-Many association using generics

In Customer class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
public Set getOrders() { return orders; }
```

In Order class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

**Example 2:** One-to-Many association without using generics

In Customer class:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=com.acme.Order.class, cascade=ALL,
        mappedBy="customer")
public Set getOrders() { return orders; }
```

In Order class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

You can do as given in this Example [OneToManyTargetEntity](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/OneToManyTargetEntity.htm).

Look at these threads:
[stackoverflow_4011472](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011472/mappedby-reference-an-unknown-target-entity-property)
[stackoverflow_9032998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032998/hibernate-cascades-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the)