# Hibernate, automatically persist dependant objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cascade

I'm quite new to Hibernate and have been trying to determine what it will do for you and what it requires you to do.

A big one is dealing with an object that has dependants that don't yet exist in the database.  For example, I have a Project object that includes a Manufacturer field that accepts a Manufacturer object as its value.  In the database I have a products table with a mfr_id column that's a reference to the manufacturers table (a fairly typical unidirectional one-to-many relationship).

If the manufacturer assigned to the product object relates to one that's already in the database then there's no problem.  However, when I try to save or update an object that references a manufacturer that hasn't been persisted yet, the operation fails with an exception.

> Exception in thread "Application" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

I can of course manually check the state of the product's manufacturer by seeing if it's ID field is null and saving it if it is, but this seems like a cumbersome solution.  Does Hibernate support automatically persisting dependants if the dependant in question isn't yet persisted?  If so, how do I enable that behaviour?  I'm using the version of Hibernate bundled with Netbeans (3.5, I believe) and inline annotations for specifying the mapping behaviour.  Below are my product and manufacturer classes, cut down to the parts that handle the dependency.  (Product extends Sellable which maps to a sellable table, using JOINED as the inheritance strategy It's that table that contains the primary key that identifies the product)

```
@Entity
@Table (
        name="products",
        schema="sellable"
)
public abstract class Product extends Sellable {
    private Manufacturer                        manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name = "mfr_id")
    public Manufacturer getManufacturer () {
        return this.manufacturer;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param manufacturer 
     */
    public Product setManufacturer (Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer   = manufacturer;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The dependant Manufacturer

```
@Entity
@Table (
        name="manufacturers",
        schema="sellable",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="mfr_name") 
)
public class Manufacturer implements Serializable {
    private Integer         mfrId       = null;
    private String          mfrName     = null;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator (name = "manufacturers_mfr_id_seq", sequenceName = "sellable.manufacturers_mfr_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "manufacturers_mfr_id_seq")
    @Column (name="mfr_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getMfrId () {
        return mfrId;
    }

    private Manufacturer setMfrId (Integer mfrId) {
        this.mfrId  = mfrId;
        return this;
    }

    @Column(name="mfr_name", unique=true, nullable=false, length=127)
    public String getMfrName () {
        return mfrName;
    }

    public Manufacturer setMfrName (String mfrName) {
        this.mfrName = mfrName;
        return this;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I tried the following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032998/hibernate-cascades-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the), but I still get the transient object exception.

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
```

I also checked what version of Hibernate is bundled with Netbeans, it's 3.2.5

UPDATE 2: I found that the following appears to apparently work as I wanted.

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

However, I suspect that this is not the cascade type I really want.  If I delete a product, I don't think deleting its associated manufacturer is the correct action, which is what I believe will happen now.

I did try creating a cascade type that consisted of all the types that were available, but that didn't work either.  I got the same exception when I tried to save a product that had an unsaved manufacturer associated with it.

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

I've seen CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE mentioned in several places, but that mode doesn't seem to be available in the version of Hibernate that comes with Netbeans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to look at cascading operations; this type of operation permits you to manage lifecycle of inner object respect their parent.

[@ManyToOne(cascade)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#cascade%28%29) if you use `Session.persist()` operation or `org.hibernate.annotations.@Cascade` if you use not JPA function `Session.saveOrUpdate()`.

This is just an example, for full doc point [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade)

For your code, if you want to automatically save `Manufacturer` when saving `Project` use:

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn (name = "mfr_id")
public Manufacturer getManufacturer () {
  return this.manufacturer;
}
```

or

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same exception about transient objects when I try to save the object.  I also tried the approach suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032998/hibernate-cascades-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the of  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) but that didn't work either

Comment: are you using saveOrUpdate()? in this case you need `org.hibernate.annotation.@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)`

Comment: At the moment I'm just using save().  I'll look at other options when I get home tonight.

Comment: SAVE_UPDATE doesn't seem to be a valid cascade type in the version of Hibernate that came with Netbeans.  The hint lists the available options as ALL, PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH or REMOVE

Comment: You are using javax.persistence.CascadeType; you have to use org.hibernate.annotation.CascadeType with org.hibernate.annotation.@Cascade annotation

Comment: Actually it's annotations, plural. :)  Giving it a try now.

Comment: The @cascade method works as I was expecting.  I guess I was just having some confusion regarding persistence annotations versus hibernates annotations.  I'm still pretty new to Hibernate and it's taking a while to figure it out.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Is preferable to use standard annotations and use Hibernate' specifics only when standard does not cover your requirements