# API Rest with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm seeing some videos about API Rest with Spring Boot and so far I've done some basics and when I tried to increase the complexity I'm getting caught.

My idea is in the Post / class, create a new class with students getting the following json:

```
{
  "nome": "Primeira Serie - A".
  "alunos": [
    "João",
    "José",
    "Maria"
  ]
}
```

And return:

```
{
  "id_classe": 101
}
```

It happens that it saves the class, but it does not save the students and I have no idea how to show only the id of the class.

I have created the following classes in Java:

**Model**

**Classe.java**

```
package com.example.classe.model;

//Import's suppressed

@Entity
@Table(name = "classe")
public class Classe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classe")
    private Set<Aluno> alunos = new HashSet<Aluno>();   

    //Get's e Set's suppressed
}
```

**Aluno.java**

```
package com.example.classe.model;

//Import's suppressed

@Entity
@Table(name = "aluno")
public class Aluno {

    private static int tempID = 0;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_classe")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Classe classe;

    public Aluno(String nome) {
        tempID++;
        this.id = tempID;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Aluno() {
    }

    //Get's e Set's suppressed  

}
```

**Repository**

**ClasseRepository.java**

```
package com.example.classe.repository;

//Import's suppressed

@Repository
public interface ClasseRepository extends JpaRepository<Classe, Integer> {

    public List<Classe> findAll();

}
```

**Controller**

**ClasseController.java**

```
package com.example.classe.controller;

//Import's suppressed

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/classe")
public class ClasseController {

    @Autowired
    private ClasseRepository classeRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Classe>> getClasse() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(classeRepo.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> salvarClasse(@RequestBody Classe classe) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(classeRepo.saveAndFlush(classe), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Am I doing everything wrong or did I not understand the concept? But I wanted to understand how to do it that way.

Thanks in advance.

Cesar Sturion

Comment: Read the documentation and tutorial. You are doing everything wrong of  course by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is totally doable, but requires several changes.
I split my answer into 2 parts:

---

### Save the students

There are several problems with saving:

1. On POST your incoming json deserialized into objects in which `Classe` has a reference to `Anuli`, but `Anuli` doesn't have a reference to`Classe`. To check it you can add a break point at the line: `return new ResponseEntity<>(...` , run in debug mode and check fields of `Anuli` in `Classe`. To fix it you can add `@JsonManagedReference` on aluni field in `Classe`. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference#37394318)
2. Hibernate can't save referenced objects by default. You have to save them one by one after saving your Classe object or just turn on Cascade persisting. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454058/hibernate-automatically-persist-dependant-objects)

So, to fix 1 and 2 `Classe` should have:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classe", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<Aluno> alunos = new HashSet<Aluno>();
```

3. You have to remove custom id generation in Alumi (I am talking about `static int tempID`). Annotation `@GeneratedValue` will perfectly generate id for you as soon as you persist an object. This custom generation breaks Hibernate support. I even not talking about that it also breaks the app after restart, not threadsafe etc.

---

### Return id only

On POST returned json represent what was returned in `classeRepo.saveAndFlush(classe)` so it's an object of `Classe`.

If you want to return exactly this:

```
{
    "id_classe": 101
}
```

Then create new class like this:

```
 public class ClasseIdVO {
    @JsonProperty("id_casse")
    private Integer id;
 // Constructors, getter, setter
```

VO - means View Object, so this object only for representation, not for persisting, etc.

You can use field name `id_casse`, but it's against Java code convention, so better add `@JsonProperty`.

Also change your saving code to `new ClasseIdVO(classeRepo.saveAndFlush(classe).getId())`

Or you can just return id as a number: `classeRepo.saveAndFlush(classe).getId()`